# Galleria not showing up on Heroku in Rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku, galleria

For my Rails app I'm using  Galleria - http://galleria.io/
It all works fine locally, but when I deploy the app to heroku, galleria is gone.

Not really sure why..

Here's my code :

```
   <div id="galleria">
     <% for image in @trip.images %>    
     <%= link_to image_tag(image.image.url(:thumb)), image.image.url(:large), :title => image.title %>
     <% end %>
   </div>
    <script>

     Galleria.run('#galleria');
     Galleria.configure({
         minScaleRatio: 1,
         maxScaleRatio: 1,


    });
    </script>
   </div>
```

application.js

```
 //= require jquery
 //= require jquery_ujs
 //= require bootstrap
 //= require galleria-1.2.7
 //= require galleria.classic.min
 //= require_tree .
```

application.css

```
*= require_self
*= require galleria.classic
*= require_tree .
```

All the files being required above are in here :

```
  app\assets\javascripts
  app\assets\stylesheets
```

And I don't see any errors in my heroku log files either, so I am bit lost here.
Any ideas why it is not showing up ?

Thank You for your time!

Comment: Can you provide us the url to your heroku app? It may be possible that some javascript is not loaded.

Comment: Yes - http://quiet-mesa-9141.herokuapp.com/trips/44. The galleria should be under twitter and fb buttons.

Answer (score 0):

The answer in more detail is here: [Where to put Galleria (jQuery image gallery framework) in Rails 3.1 Asset Pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7248199/where-to-put-galleria-jquery-image-gallery-framework-in-rails-3-1-asset-pipeli?rq=1)

I had to change this line in galleria.classic.js

```
css: 'galleria.classic.css',
```

with

```
css: false,
```

And it worked!